# CorePlot incompatible type for argument 1 of initWithFrame

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-plot

I have downloaded CorePlot a week ago and have included in one of my MAC application projects. Everything works fine in Debug but when I try to build it using Distribution build it fails with this error "incompatible type for argument 1 of initWithFrame"

Here is where it is happening...

```
pieChart = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CPXYGraph` is a `CALayer`, so `CGRectZero` is correct. The problem is that more than one class has an `-initWithFrame:` method. `+alloc` returns an `id` so the compiler doesn't know which class to choose and sometimes it picks the wrong one. You can solve this with a type cast, like this:

```
pieChart = [(CPXYGraph *)[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the reply. I am at work. Will give it a go when I finish work and let you know.

Comment: I just tried that Eric and unfortunately same 6 errors are there. ld: warning: in /Users/.../Source/build/Debug/CorePlot.framework/CorePlot, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386). Any Idea???

Comment: Check your build architecture settings in the Core Plot project build settings. You might also need to do a clean build.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a Mac OS X application, unlike UIKit, Application Kit generally takes geometry from NS* structures. So, you want NSZeroRect, not CGRectZero. Also, when you generate these structures, you'll want to use the macro `NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h)` rather than the CoreGraphics `CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)`.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the reply. I have changed that to NSZeroRect. Now error has gone from here but I am getting these 6 errors all for different classes of coreplot. One of them is ld: warning: in /Users/.../Source/build/Debug/CorePlot.framework/CorePlot, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386) ".obj_class_name_CPTextLayer" referenced from: